# Python: Add Same Prefix to All Elements in List

Tags: python, list, loops, addition, prefix

Let's say I have the following Python List:

```
['7831-0', nan, '3165-0', '7831-0', '7831-1']
```

I want to add the same prefix ('ADD_' to each element in the above list.  I also want to remove the nan from my list.  My desired output list is as follows:

```
list = ['ADD_7831-0', 'ADD_3165-0', 'ADD_7831-0', 'ADD_7831-1']
```

I tried the following code:

```
prefix_ADD = 'ADD_'

new_list = [prefix_ADD + x for x in list]
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: must be str, not float
```

Comment: @Pine-Nuts[0] - interested in pandas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[prefix_ADD + x for x in list if not str(x) == "nan"]`

Is one way you could filter out nan

Answer (score 3):

```
your_list = ['7831-0', float('nan'), '3165-0', '7831-0', '7831-1']
print(your_list)  # ['7831-0', nan, '3165-0', '7831-0', '7831-1']
prefix_ADD = 'ADD_'
new_list = [prefix_ADD + x for x in your_list if isinstance(x, str)]
print(new_list)  # ['ADD_7831-0', 'ADD_3165-0', 'ADD_7831-0', 'ADD_7831-1']
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a less elegant solution but how about this:

```
new_list=[]
old_list = ['7831-0', nan, '3165-0', '7831-0', '7831-1']

prefix_ADD = 'ADD_'

for x in old_list:
    if x != nan:
        new_list.append(prefix_ADD + x)

print(new_list)
# ['ADD_7831-0', 'ADD_3165-0', 'ADD_7831-0', 'ADD_7831-1']
```